# E-Commerce Comparison: Handling Product Nomenclature

Tags: c#, asp.net, e-commerce, data-import

I am working on an E-Commerce Comparison Site where we are getting the listings for our database from multiple websites, we have been using the feeds provided to us, but as the two websites have their own feed structure as well as nomenclature I am facing the issue of multiple entries of the same product.

We then thought, crawling would help us with the issue but the it still prevailed. The aim is to get the products under one ID. As an example

```
Site 1:
Product Name: IPhone 6S 16GB Gold

Site 2: 
Product Name: Iphone 6S
```

The product from Site 2 is the same as the one from Site 1, meaning it is a 16GB Model and Gold in color, but as the nomenclature is different it can't be added against the same ID in my database.

If anyone has had this issue then it would be grateful if you could tell me how you were able to resolve it.

Comment: You can create a table with aliases of Product.  Say it contain two rows `IPhone 6S 16GB Gold` and `Iphone 6S` but unique ID or something to know that they are same.

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you  want. Obviously, you need your own nomenclature directory, and mapping for each site. The main problem is to discover, that your "iPhone 6S" and their "IPhone 6S" or "iPhone 6 S" are the same, when creating mapping data.

Comment: That would need me to comb through all the data that has been added in my database which is over 30 lac records.

Comment: Yes, this is well-known problem for accounting/warehouse software. There's no 100% effective solution. You can look at different string comparison algorithms, if you want to automate this process.

Comment: Even huge companies have trouble with this; if you browse Amazon you will often see the same product showing up under slightly different names and different product IDs.  One (imperfect) solution is to use [unique product identifiers](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160161?hl=en), but this can only work if your various feeds contain them.

Comment: I am also facing the same kind of issue. I am trying to compare the product from Flipkart, Snapdeal and Amazon.in.

Please respond if any one has same experience.